# Need to avoid duplication of cover image in Kindle book (tex4ebook)

Tags: tex4ebook

`tex4ebook` includes the cover as the first page of the book.  However, the Kindle automatically includes the cover as the first page, getting the cover from the OPF file. The result is a duplicate cover page. (Section 3.2.3 of the Kindle Publishing Guidelines says "Internal Cover Must Not Appear Twice").

Is there a way to specify the cover image so that it goes into the OPF file, but not into the HTML?  Thanks!

Comment: My answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213448/291) to your other question raises also this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use trick I showed you earlier to include file with `\special{t4ht+@File: filename}`. You won't use `\CoverImage` command this way, so you will also need to make some additional configurations:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\special{t4ht+@File: cover.jpg}
\Configure{CoverMimeType}{image/jpeg}
\CoverMetadata{cover.jpg}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Use `\Configure{CoverMimeType}` only if the cover image isn't in `png` format

Comment: Thanks @michal.h21... I hacked a different solution which involves snipping out the display code (as posted in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213369/two-navigation-issues-for-kindle-and-other-ebooks/).  Haven't tested this but it is obviously better...