# Making index in Pandoc generated ebook

Tags: indexing, polyglossia, pandoc, ebook

I would like to make the example I have written [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429699/using-imakeidx-in-tex4ebook-with-polyglossia-for-devanagari) to work in Pandoc. When run using `pandoc input-tex-file -o output-epub-file`, pandoc produces a nice ebook using this tex file. However, the ebook lacks the indexes. How can I get the indexes in the output ebook?

Comment: Pandoc has no native support for indices. Maybe you could write a filter...

Comment: Filter example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65656823/156060

Answer (score 1):

You can add index to you Pandoc generated ebook using the two steps:

1. Adding identifier to your heading, for example the following `{#foo}` syntax added the identifier `for` to the heading `My heading`,

```
# My heading {#foo}
```

we assume the file name was `chap01.md`.

2. Creating a index type of file as your book index. In this file, you can write book index using markdown link format. eg:

```
# Index {epub:type=index}

#. [Index to My heading ](#foo)
```

we assume the file name was `index.md`.

Finally, your can generate the ebook with index using:

```
pandoc index.md chap01.md -s -o indexed_ebook.epub
```

Comment: This looks like a table of contents, rather than an index. Are you sure this is, what the OP meant?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, often the first thing an editor does when transforming to an eBook e.g. ePUB is to remove the table of content page. This is because the eReader will generate a table of content based on the hierarchy of the document, and it will make it available through some special interactions, in the eBooks the page where a content is present will change depending on the setting the user uses (e.g. font-size) so there is no need for a page containing the table of content!

Pandoc actually can generate a table of content using `--toc` flag but this won't work with ePUB for the aforementioned reasons.