# Error with latest tex4ebook and biblatex using Texlive 2017 (Windows)

Tags: biblatex, texlive-2017, tex4ebook

I am using the test setup from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348098/book-template-for-tex4ebook).

I updated my Texlive 2017 packages and now the file will not process and gives an error:

```
   Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
   Package biblatex Info: ... file 'sample.bbl' found.

   (./sample.bbl
   ! Undefined control sequence.
   \entry ...a@\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@scheme
                                                  @\abx@field@entrykey }\csu...
   l.22     \entry{Hiemenz}{book}{}

   ?x
```

The file ran ok before the update. Does anyone else get the same error?

Thanks.

Update:

The various files are:

sample.tex

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{Hiemenz,
author={Hiemenz},
title={Polymer Chemistry}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=auto,backref=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc=true,columns=1,noautomatic]

\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}

\title{Book}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents \newpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{C1}

aword\index{aword}

\lipsum \newpage

Here comes a quotation \cite{Hiemenz}.

\chapter{C2}

bword\index{bword}
\lipsum \newpage

\backmatter

\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography \newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\indexprologue{Concepts}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

build.mk4:

```
Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
Make:add("xindy", function(par)
  -- par.encoding  = par.encoding or "utf8"
  -- par.language = par.language or "english"
  par.idxfile = par.idxfile or par.input .. ".idx"
  local modules = par.modules or {}
  local t = {}
  for k,v in ipairs(modules) do
    t[#t+1] = "-M ".. v
  end
  par.moduleopt = table.concat(t, " ")
  local xindy_call = "xindy -L ${language} -C ${encoding} ${moduleopt} ${idxfile}" % par
  print(xindy_call)
  return os.execute("xindy -L ${language} -C ${encoding} ${moduleopt} ${idxfile}" % par)
end, {modules = {"texindy"}, language = "english", encoding = "utf8"})

if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
 Make:htlatex {}
 Make:biber {}
 -- xindymodule = Make.params["input"]
 Make:xindy {modules = {"sample"}}
 Make:htlatex {}
 Make:htlatex {}
 Make:htlatex {}
end
```

ebook.cfg:

```
% save the clearpage before it is redefined by tex4ht
\let\oldclrearpage\clearpage
% define macro for newpage insertion
\def\mypagebreak{\Configure{newpage}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="newpage"></div>}}}
%
\Preamble{xhtml}
\CutAt{section}
%
% enforce newpage
%
% define it for \newpage
%
\mypagebreak
\Css{.newpage{page-break-before:always;}}
% modify \Configure{BODY} so our confiurations work on all extracted pages
\Configure{@BODY}{\def\clearpage{\bgroup\mypagebreak\oldclrearpage\egroup}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\global\let\clearpage\oldclrearpage\Configure{newpage}{}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

imakeindx.4ht:

```
\RequirePackage[]{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{gettitlestring}
\newcounter{indexcnt}
\let\@Index\@index
\patchcmd{\@Index}{\@wrindex}{\@Wrindex}{}{}
\let\@Wrindex\@wrindex
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\thepage}{\theindexcnt}{}{}
\let\xIndex\index
\patchcmd{\xIndex}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}
\patchcmd{\xIndex}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}

\pretocmd{\xIndex}{\@stepindexcnt\@indexanchor}
% \patchcmd{\index}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}
% \patchcmd{\xIndex}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}
% \let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% \let\@index\@Index
% \patchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\protected@write}{\protected@iwrite}{}{}
\let\Index\xIndex
\let\index\xIndex
%\show\Index
\newcommand\@indexanchor{%
  \edef\idx@anch{idx-anch\theindexcnt}%
  \Link[]{}{\idx@anch}\EndLink%
  %\Ref{(idx-link-\idx@anch)}{\FileName/\idx@anch}
}
\newcommand\@stepindexcnt{\stepcounter{indexcnt}}
\newcommand\hello[1]{\@hello#1}
\def\@hello#1/{%
  \Link{idx-anch#1}{}#1\EndLink%
}


\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand\LaTeX{LaTeX}
}

\newcount\idxkwdcnt
\LinkCommand\IdxKWLink{span,href,id}
\newcommand\idxkeyword[1]{%
  \global\advance\idxkwdcnt by 1\relax%
  % use tags only one time
  \GetTitleString{#1}
  \ifcsdef{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}{}%
  %{\Tag{idxkw#1}{idxkw\the\idxkwdcnt}}%
  {\expandafter\Tag\expandafter{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}{idxkw\the\idxkwdcnt}}%
  \csgdef{idxkw\GetTitleStringResult}{x}
  \a:IdxKW{}{idxkw\the\idxkwdcnt}#1\b:IdxKW
}
```

the command line is:

```
tex4ebook -c ebook -e build.mk4 -f epub -s -r 167 sample
```

Note that a normal latex run using

```
latexmk -pdf sample
```

works fine so it seems an issue between tex4ebook and biblatex.

Comment: Try deleting the `.bbl` file. If an update of biblatex and/or biber is involved they may not like old auxiliary files.

Comment: @TeXnician I did a clean run without any aux files but the error is still there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I wasn't clear. I deleted all the generated files including bbl before the run.

Comment: Show a complete example that can be tested.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please see the update. These are basically the files from the linked question. Everything worked fine before the latest update. I checked with a version of Texlive before the update and it still works. I am going back to using this version for now.

Comment: Oh, how neat. biblatex.4ht tests for the biblatex version with `\ifdim\abx@version pt < 3.3pt` and now we reached version 3.10.

Comment: You could try e.g. `\makeatletter \def\abx@version{4}\makeatother` in your preamble, but I don't know if biblatex will complain. And make a bug report .

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your suggestion works thanks. I will submit a bug report.

Comment: I adready wrote Michal a mail (but if you can add an issue to the tex4ht tracker, if won't do any harm, I don't have an account there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ulrike already pointed out, this is a bug in `tex4ht` support for Biblatex. It keeps some macros intended for the older Biblatex versions and it use some tests for their loading:

```
\ifdim\abx@version pt < 3.3pt
```

The problem is that the current Biblatex version is 3.10 and it test positively in this test. So the wrong macros are loaded. I think that we can safely remove these old macros, in order to prevent similar issues in the future. If someone keeps recent version of tex4ht, it is likely that he also keeps the recent version of Biblatex, so it doesn't have a point to keep it anyway.

Try the updated `biblatex.4ht`:

```
% biblatex.4ht (2017-11-16-15:46), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2007-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2017 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2017-11-16-15:46}

   \def\make:blx:ver#1.#2#3\relax{%
   %\ifdim#1pt< 3pt \xdef\blx:ver:no{2}\else\xdef\blx:ver:no{3}\fi%
   \gdef\blx:ver:no{#1}
   \gdef\blx:subver:no{#2}
}
\expandafter\make:blx:ver\abx@version.0\relax
\ifx\a:printshorthands\Undef\let\blx@shorthands\@empty\fi
\ifx\blx@startbib\:UnDef
 \pend:def\blx@shorthands{%
   \pend:def\blx@bibinit{%
       \HAssign\shorthands:cnt=0
       \NewConfigure{printfield-shorthand}{2}%
       \Configure{printfield-shorthand}%
         {\gHAdvance\shorthands:cnt by 1\relax
          \ifnum \shorthands:cnt=1 \a:printshorthands
          \else                    \c:printshorthands \fi
         }
         {\d:printshorthands}%
   \append:def\endtheshorthands{\b:printshorthands}%
   \csname a:@shorthands\endcsname}
}
\ifx\b:printshorthands\Undef\let\endtheshorthands\@empty\fi
\def\a:entryhead{CVR}
\def\a:entryhead:full{CV Radhakrishnan}
\ifx\bib@macro@entryhead:name\UnDef
  \let\bib@macro@entryhead:name\@empty\fi
\ifx\bib@macro@entryhead:full\UnDef
  \let\bib@macro@entryhead:full\@empty\fi
  \gdef\BibFileName[#1]#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname
       BibFileName#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcount\sv:sec:cnt
\def\bibSecConfigure{%
  \let\save:section\section
  \global\sv:sec:cnt=\c@secnumdepth
  \def\section{\@ifstar
      {\c@secnumdepth=0\relax\save:section}%
      {\c@secnumdepth=\sv:sec:cnt\save:section}}%
}
\gHAssign\bibN=0
  \:CheckOption{ooffice}\if:Option
   \def\bibConfigure{\ConfigureList{thebibliography}%
      {\IgnorePar\EndP \gHAdvance\bib:N by 1
       \HCode{<text:bibliography text:name="bib-\bib:N" >
              <text:bibliography-source>\Hnewline
             <text:index-title-template>}
           \NoFonts\ref:name\EndNoFonts
       \HCode{</text:index-title-template>\Hnewline
%
           <text:bibliography-entry-template\Hnewline
            text:bibliography-type="custom1"
            text:style-name="Bibliography11">\Hnewline
%
            <text:index-entry-bibliography
             text:bibliography-data-field="identifier"/>\Hnewline
%
           <text:index-entry-span>: </text:index-entry-span>\Hnewline
           <text:index-entry-bibliography
            text:bibliography-data-field="author" />\Hnewline
           <text:index-entry-span>, </text:index-entry-span>\Hnewline
%
           <text:index-entry-bibliography
            text:bibliography-data-field="title" />\Hnewline
           <text:index-entry-span>, </text:index-entry-span>\Hnewline
%
           <text:index-entry-bibliography
            text:bibliography-data-field="year" />\Hnewline
           </text:bibliography-entry-template>\Hnewline\Hnewline
           </text:bibliography-source>\Hnewline
           <text:index-body>\Hnewline}%
         \let\en:bib=\empty
      }%
      {\en:bib\HCode{</text:index-body></text:bibliography>}}
      {\en:bib\gdef\en:bib{\HCode{</text:p>\Hnewline}}%
        \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="p-bibitem">}%
        \gHAdvance\bibN by 1
        \HCode{<text:reference-mark
          text:name="X0-\csname BIB-\bibN\endcsname">%
          </text:reference-mark>}%
      }%
      {}{}
  }

  \else
    \def\bibConfigure{%
  \ConfigureList{thebibliography}
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP \EndP
    \HCode {<dl class="thebibliography">}%
%
% This is for linking citations with biblist items which
% are in a different file when output is split into different
% chunks. [CVR 2012-09-27]
%
%
% <biblatex-2.2>
%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\BibFileName[\therefsection]{\FileName}}%
%
% </biblatex-2.2>
%
    \PushMacro \end:itm \global \let \end:itm =\empty}%
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP
    \PopMacro \end:itm \global \let \end:itm \end:itm \EndP
    \HCode {</dd></dl>}\ShowPar}%
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP \gHAdvance \bibN by 1
    \end:itm \global \def \end:itm {\EndP \Tg </dd>}%
    \HCode {<dt id="X\therefsection-\abx@field@entrykey"
      class="thebibliography">}\bgroup \bf}%
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP
    \egroup
    \HCode {</dt><dd\Hnewline id="bib-\bibN"
      class="thebibliography">}%
    \par \ShowPar}%
 }

 \fi
\NewConfigure{printshorthands}{4}
\NewConfigure{@shorthands}[1]{\concat:config\a:@shorthands{#1}}
\let\a:@shorthands\empty
\def\nolinkurl{\o:url:}
% \def\blx@checksum{\ifx \blx@checksum@old \blx@checksum@new \else
%   \blx@warning@noline {Page references have changed.\MessageBreak
%     Rerun to get references right}\@tempswatrue \blx@reruntrue \fi
%   \@nameuse {blx@rerun}}
\def\blx@checksum#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@tempcnta\the\numexpr0#2*0#3\relax
  \blx@tempcntb\blx@tempcnta
  \divide\blx@tempcntb10
  \multiply\blx@tempcntb10
  \advance\blx@tempcnta-\blx@tempcntb
  \xdef#1{#1\the\blx@tempcnta}%
  \endgroup}
\pend:def\blx@bibliography{\bibSecConfigure%
  \pend:def\blx@bibinit{%
    \bibConfigure
     \csname onthebibliography:list\endcsname
  }%
}
\let\en:bib\@empty
\newcounter{bib}
\ifnum\blx:ver:no < 3
 \protected\def\blx@bbl@entry#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \def\texht@bibkey{#1}
  \edef\abx@field@entrykey{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \global\advance\c@bib 1
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef
    \string\csname\space BIB-\thebib\string\endcsname
     {\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\texht@bibkey}}%
  \Tag{)QX\therefsection-#1}{\thebib}%
  \blx@setoptions@type{#2}%
  \blx@bbl@options{#3}%
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \edef\blx@bbl@data{blx@data@\the\c@refsection @\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \csuse\blx@bbl@data
  \cslet\blx@bbl@data\@empty
  \blx@bbl@addfield{entrykey}{\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \blx@bbl@addfield{entrytype}{#2}%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{options}
    {}
    {\blx@bbl@fieldedef{options}{\expandonce\abx@field@options}}}
%
 \protected\def\blx@finentry{%
  \unspace
  \a:finentry
      \finentrypunct
      \blx@postpunct
  \b:finentry
  \blx@initunit
 }
%
\else
% Biblatex 3.0
%
% Hacks for biblatex
% MakeUppercase is redefined by tex4ht, biblatex tries to redefine it as well, but it relies on original
% LaTeX version:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{%
    \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
    \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##1##2\reserved@a}%
    \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{#1}}%
    \reserved@a
}}
% Same applies also for \MakeLowercase
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeLowercase}[1]{{%
    \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##2##1\reserved@a}%
    \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\lowercase{#1}}%
    \reserved@a
}}

% I don't really understand this, but language processing is broken by default
% with biblatex. It loads language file, but it executes code which should be
% executed only in the case if the language file fails, it displays an error message
% and language handling doesn't work. When we execute following code, the language
% files are loaded before checking of the success and it seems to work.

\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
      {% This is required for languages which are never explicitly selected
        \def\do#1{\blx@lbxinput{#1}{}{}}%
       \ifx\@empty\bbl@loaded\else%
       \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\bbl@loaded}%
      \fi}{}%

\fi % end of version boolean
\NewConfigure{finentry}{2}
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:printfield-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{printfield-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{printfield-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:printfield-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:printfield-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@printfield:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@printfield\endcsname\:tempc
\NewConfigure{printfield}[1]{\def\a:printfield##1{#1}}
\Configure{printfield}{%
    \Configure{#1}%
       {\HCode{<!--#1-->}}%
       {\HCode{<!--/#1-->}}%
}
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:bibstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{bibstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{bibstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:bibstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:bibstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@bibstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@bibstring\endcsname\:tempc
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:bibcpstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{bibcpstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{bibcpstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:bibcpstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:bibcpstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@bibcpstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@bibcpstring\endcsname\:tempc
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:biblcstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{biblcstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{biblcstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:biblcstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:biblcstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@biblcstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@biblcstring\endcsname\:tempc
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:bibucstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{bibucstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{bibucstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:bibucstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:bibucstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@bibucstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@bibucstring\endcsname\:tempc
\NewConfigure{biblatex-style}[2]{%
   \def\:temp{#1}%
   \ifx \:temp\blx@cbxfile
      #2%
      \global\let\biblatex:style\def
   \fi
}

\def\biblatex:style{}
\Configure{biblatex-style}{}{}

\pend:def\at:docend{%
   \ifx \UnDef\biblatex:style
      \:warning{\string\Configure{biblatex-style}{\blx@cbxfile}{...}
         not available}%
   \fi
}
\let\blx:item\@item
\def\@item[#1]{%
  \blx:item[#1]%
  \ifhmode \spacefactor\blx@sf@par\fi
}
\let\blx@resetpuncthook\@empty
\let\blx@csq@ifkernmark\@empty
\newskip\blx@unitmark
\blx@unitmark=10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\let\abx@aux@page\@gobbletwo
\let\abx@aux@fnpage\@gobbletwo
\let\abx@aux@refsection\@gobbletwo
%
% <Kristian.Debrabant@cs.kuleuven.be> reported that After updating
% biblatex and biblatex.ht to versions 2.2 respectively
% 2012-09-28-17:49 (using MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit), tex4ht seemed no longer
% respected the defernumbers option in biblatex.sty: When applied to
% the attached file tex4hterror.tex.
%
% The problem was due to nullifying \abx@aux@number which in fact
% should have been redefined to \blx@aux@number when defernumbers
% option is true.
%
% This is done now and as per Kristian, the fix works fine now.
%
\ifnum\blx:ver:no < 3
%
 \protected\def\blx@aux@number#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@bbl@addentryfield{\detokenize{#2}}{#3}{localnumber}{#4}%
  \ifblank{#4}%
    {}%
    {\csgdef{blx@labelnumber@#3}{#4}%
     %\blx@addchecksum{#1}{#4} % this can cause a nodocument error!
     }}
%
 \iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}%
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{labelnumber}%
     \let\blx@thelabelnumber\blx@addlabelnumber
     \let\abx@aux@number\blx@aux@number}%
    {\let\blx@thelabelnumber\relax
     \let\abx@aux@number\@gobblefour}
%
\else
  \def\@gobblefive#1#2#3#4#5{}%
 \protected\def\blx@aux@number#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \blx@bbl@addentryfield{\detokenize{#2}}{#3}{localnumber}{#4}{#5}%
   \blx@bbl@addentryfield{\detokenize{#2}}{#3}{labelnumber}{#4}{#5}%
   \global\toggletrue{blx@localnumber}%
   \ifblank{#5}
    {}
    {\csgdef{blx@labelnumber@#3@#4}{#5}}}

 \iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}%
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{labelnumber}%
     \let\blx@thelabelnumber\blx@addlabelnumber
     \let\abx@aux@number\blx@aux@number}%
    {\let\blx@thelabelnumber\relax
     \let\abx@aux@number\@gobblefive}
\fi % end of version boolean
%
\AtEndDocument{%
  \def\abx@aux@page#1#2{\blx@addpagesum{#1}{#2}}%
  \def\abx@aux@fnpage#1#2{\blx@addpagesum{#1}{#2}}%
}
%
\def\blx@begunit{%
  \toggletrue{blx@tempa}%
  \iftoggle{blx@insert}%
    {\iftoggle{blx@unit}%
       {\begingroup
          \let\blx@begunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endnounit\@empty
          \blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct
        \endgroup
        \global\togglefalse{blx@unit}%
        \togglefalse{blx@tempa}}
       {\blx@postpunct}%
     \iftoggle{blx@block}%
       {\begingroup
          \let\blx@begunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endnounit\@empty
          \newblockpunct
        \endgroup
        \global\togglefalse{blx@block}%
        \togglefalse{blx@tempa}}%
       {}}%
    {}%
  \blx@postpunct
  \blx@resetpuncthook
  \iftoggle{blx@tempa}%
    {}%
    {\global\togglefalse{blx@insert}}%
  \csname a:blx@unit\endcsname
  \blx@leavevmode
  \blx@csq@ifkernmark
    {}%
    {\penalty\@M
    \hskip-\blx@unitmark\relax
    \hskip\blx@unitmark\relax
    }%
  \begingroup
    \Configure{blx@unit}{}{}%
}
\def\blx@endunit{%
  \endgroup
  \csname b:blx@unit\endcsname
  \Configure{blx@unit}{}{}%
  \ifdim\lastskip=\blx@unitmark
    \unskip\unskip\unpenalty
    \global\togglefalse{blx@lastins}%
  \else
   \global\toggletrue{blx@insert}%
   \global\toggletrue{blx@lastins}%
 \fi
}
\NewConfigure{blx@unit}{2}
%
   \else
\fi


   \NewConfigure{thebibliography}{4}
\append:def\blx@bibinit{\a:bibinit}%
\NewConfigure{bibinit}{1}%

   \let\blx@anchors\@empty
\let\bib@field@entrykey\@empty

\protected\def\blx@anchor{%
  \xifinlist{X\the\c@refsection -%@
    \bib@field@entrykey}{\blx@anchors}%
    {}%
    {\listxadd\blx@anchors{X\the\c@refsection -%@
      \bib@field@entrykey}%
     \hyper:natanchorstart{X\the\c@refsection -%@
      \bib@field@entrykey}%
     \hyper:natanchorend}}

\protected\def\blx@bibhyperref{%
   \@ifnextchar[%]
     {\blx@bibhyperref@i}%
     {\blx@bibhyperref@i[\bib@field@entrykey]}}%

\long\def\blx@bibhyperref@i[#1]#2{%
   \hyper:natlinkstart{X\the\c@refsection -%@
     #1}%
     #2\hyper:natlinkend}%

\protected\long\def\blx@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
   \hyper:natlinkstart{X\the\c@refsection -%:
     #1}%
     #2\hyper:natlinkend}%

\protected\long\def\blx@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
   \@bsphack
   \hyper:natanchorstart{X\the\c@refsection -%:
     #1}%
   \@esphack
     #2\hyper:natanchorend}%

\let\blx@ifhyperref\@firstoftwo

% Oleg Domanov odomanov@yandex.ru reports:
% tex4ht ends with an error when compiles biblatex files. I'm on
% Windows, texlive 2012. I put here a minimal example and files
% generated with the command latexmk test && mk4ht oolatex test
%
% https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn1zm40htqs13mf/t4htlink.zip
%
% There is a superfluous \relax in the file test.tmp, line 65 which
% seems to cause the error.
%
% Changes to cope with biblatex upgrade caused this problem. It is now
% fixed. --CVR 2012/10/26
%
\:CheckOption{ooffice}\if:Option
 \def\hyper:natanchorstart#1{\Link{}{#1}\EndLink}%
 \def\hyper:natlinkstart#1{\Link{#1}{}}%
\else
 \def\hyper:natanchorstart#1{%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname\relax%
        \Tag{)Qpage.\thepage}{\file:id}%
        \HCode{<a id="page.\thepage"></a>}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname{0}%
       \fi
      \Link[\csname BibFileName\therefsection\endcsname]{}{#1}\EndLink}
 \def\hyper:natlinkstart#1{%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname\relax%
        \Tag{)Qpage.\thepage}{\file:id}%
        \HCode{<a id="page.\thepage"></a>}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname{0}%
       \fi
      \Link[\csname BibFileName\therefsection\endcsname]{#1}{}}
\fi
\def\hyper:natanchorend{}
\def\hyper:natlinkend{\EndLink}
\def\writeCiteLink#1{\immediate\write\@mainaux{%
    \string\@namedef{#1.\thepage}{\FileName}}}
\let\blx@addpagesum\@gobbletwo
\let\nolinkurl\relax

\ifx\blx:ver:no < 3
%
% biblatex 2.9a
%
% Newly added to process {keylist} environment (CVR)
%
\let\keylist\description
\let\endkeylist\enddescription
\def\keyitem#1{\item[#1]}%
%
%
\else
%
% biblatex 3.0
%
\let\keylist\Un:def
\let\endkeylist\Un:def
\newenvironment*{keylist}
  {\list{}{%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.25in}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{10pt}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
     \raggedright%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss\bfseries##1}}}
  {\endlist}
%
\def\keyitem#1{%
  \item[#1]
  \begingroup
    \keyitemhook%
    \blx@bibinit%
    \midsentence\ifbibstring{#1}{}{\latintext}\biblstring{#1}%
    \expandafter\lbx@initnamehook\lsmartoftext%
    \par\nobreak
    \midsentence\ifbibstring{#1}{}{\latintext}\bibsstring{#1}%
    \expandafter\lbx@initnamehook\ssmartoftext%
  \endgroup
  \par\nobreak}
\fi  % End of version boolean

\ConfigureList{keylist}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<dl \a:LRdir class="description">}%
      \PushMacro\end:itm
\global\let\end:itm=\empty}%
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\EndP\HCode{</dd></dl>}\ShowPar}%
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</dd>}\HCode{<dt
        class="description">}\bgroup \bf}%
   {\egroup\EndP\HCode{</dt><dd\Hnewline class="description">}}

   \let\:temp\do
  \def\do#1{%
    \patchcmd#1%
      {\color@begingroup}%
      {\color@begingroup\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}%
      {\togglefalse{blx@tempa}\listbreak}%
      {}}%
  \docsvlist{%
    \@footnotetext,%          latex
    \H@@footnotetext,%        hyperref
    \scr@saved@footnotetext,% koma-script 3.x
    \l@dold@footnotetext,%    ledmac
    \l@doldold@footnotetext,% ledmac
    \@fntORI}%                frenchle
\let\do\:temp

\Hinput{biblatex}
\endinput
```

It produces the correct result:

[image]