# Sample LaTeX book repo for EPub with tex4ebook?

Tags: memoir, tex4ebook

I'm writing a nonfiction book with the memoir class and the usual parts (cover art, colophon, dedication, foreword, parts, chapters, creations, etc.).

I finished the print version. I'm amazed at how well tex4ebook coverts to EPub but I am seeing I need to simplify my formatting in places and adapt to what tex4ebook expects.

Are there any sample repos for LaTeX books that convert nicely with tex4epub? I feel like I'm going down a well trodden path and would love a shortcut.

Comment: I found the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348098/book-template-for-tex4ebook) might make a decent repo. I have it running and will build repo and make it available when done. The only issue I'm running into is the `newpage` commands are ignored in ReadEra.

Comment: You can try to add some CSS frameworks using the [\Configure{AddCss}](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html#document-styling-using-css) command, but the problem is still the incomplete CSS support in ePub readers :/